# jQuery touchstart on multiple element

Tags: javascript, jquery, mobile-safari, jquery-events

I looking for a solution for iOS, like hover in the 'desktop world'.
I have a lot of image item on my page, and when the user move his finger across the images, the actual image gets opacity 0. (so one move hides all item :) )

I tried something like this:

```
 $("img").on "touchstart", ->  
        $(this).animate({opacity:0}, 100)
```

Answer (score -1):

If you want to hide all images when one recive the `touchstart`-event you should use:

```
$("img").on("touchstart", function() {  
    $("img").animate({opacity:0}, 100);
});
```

Or even better:

```
var $images = $("img").on("touchstart", function() {  
    $images.fadeTo(100, 0);
});
```

The `this` keyword refers the the DOM Element receiving the event rater then the whole jQuery collection.

Not good with CoffeeScript.

```
$(document.body).on "touchmove", (event) ->
  if $(event.target).is("img")
    $(event.target).animate
      opacity: 0
    , 100
```

Comment: @Dodjs Have you looked into using `touchmove`. Maybe with `event.target`?